# Why is GCC saying a variable is unused when it is not?

Tags: c, gcc

GCC is saying **snr_db** is unused when I set -Wall flag, but this variable is used. When i initialize it outside the scope of the for, gcc stops warning me. Does anyone know why is that?

```
double snr_db;
double snr_db_step = #WHATHEVER

for (int interval = 1, snr_db = 20.0; interval <= intervals; interval++, snr_db -= snr_db_step) {
    snr_lin = pow(10.0, snr_db / 10.0);
    bit_err_rate = ber_bpsk(snr_lin);
    //CODE CONTINUES
}
```

Comment: Try `-Wshadow` for a more explicit explanation by the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existing answers already addressed the root of the problem: This `for` loop

```
for (int interval = 1, snr_db = 20.0; [...]; [...]) {
```

**declares** two variables of type `int`, one of them happens to shadow the `double snr_db` of the outer scope. For a deeper understanding, let's add some background.

From **[N1570 (latest draft for C11)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), §6.8.5.3 p1**:

> The statement
>
> `for` `(` *clause-1* `;` *expression-2* `;` *expression-3* `)` *statement*
>
> behaves as follows: The expression *expression-2* is the controlling expression that is
>   evaluated before each execution of the loop body. The expression *expression-3* is
>   evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body. If *clause-1* is a
>   declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and
>   the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is reached in the order of execution
>   before the first evaluation of the controlling expression. If *clause-1* is an expression, it is
>   evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling expression.

So, with `for`, the *clause-1* can be either a *declaration* or an *expression*. In your example, it is a *declaration*. In a declaration, a comma has the meaning to separate multiple declarators, declaring multiple objects of the same type.

On the other hand, inside an expression, a comma is an operator that evaluates both operands *sequenced* and the result of the evaluation is that of the right-hand side operand. This is also often used in `for` loops. As *clause-1* is evaluated as a void expression, the result doesn't matter, only the side-effects are relevant. Therefore, one way to write your code correctly would look like this:

```
[...]
int interval;
for (interval = 1, snr_db = 20.0; [...]; [...]) {
```

Now, *clause-1* is an expression with the comma-operator separating two different assignment expressions (that have the side-effect of setting a new value to the variable). But this form  has the drawback that the scope of `interval` is needlessly extended to the scope surrounding your loop.

Of course, *declarations* can **contain** *expressions* in their initializers, so one way to write *exactly* what you originally wanted would look like this:

```
for (int interval = (snr_db = 20.0), 1; [...]; [...]) {
```

Now, only `interval` is declared and its initializer uses the comma-operator to first carry out the side-effect of `snr_db = 20.0`, but still evaluate to `1` (the right-hand side of the comma) to initialize `interval`. Although this is correct and as an advanced C programmer, you should understand how it works, **never write such code in practice**. It's just too confusing in requiring even an experienced programmer to stop and think about what exactly this is doing when reading the code.

Therefore, the best alternative is to keep the declaration of `interval` as your *clause-1* and move the assignment to `snr_db` just before your loop:

```
snr_db = 20.0;
for (int interval = 1; [...]; [...]) {
```

Answer (score 12):

Actually it is not used. You declared it `double` -

```
double snr_db; // this is unused
```

But in the `for` loop-

```
for (int interval = 1, snr_db = 20.0; ..)
```

In this `snr_db` is `int` here (this is same case as `int x,y;`, both are `int` as being part of *declaration*) and over shadows the one declared above this loop body.

Therefore, `double snr_db;` remains unused.

You could do this-

```
double snr_db;
int interval; 

for(interval = 1, snr_db =20.0;..){....}  // only intialization
 /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this would be a different case from above as here
',' does work as comma operator therefore, evaluating both the expressions. */
```

Comment: How is `nsr_db` an `int` within `for`?

Comment: I'm surprised that there wasn't a compiler error thrown for the redefinition of a variable type which would otherwise have been within scope.

Comment: @GauravSehgal it's part of a declaration list with type `int`

Comment: @Zhro It won't be because while defined in loop it will be considered only inside body of loop and not in complete scope of program.

Comment: @ameyCU I think this should have just a bit of explanation why this comma is not the *comma operator* here. Otherwise very nice answer.

Comment: @ameyCU IMO, it's scary that the compiler even lets you do that.

Comment: @ameyCU, there is no need to move `interval` variable outside of for loop scope. `snr_db` can be initialized to `20.0` to begin with and can be updated later in the for loop update part

Comment: @Rishi Yes, that's good way to work also keeping `interval` only is loop.

Answer (score 5):

Your `for` loop is declaring *two* `int`  variables, including one (also and confusingly named `snr_db`) which shadows the outer `double` with a nested lexical [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping). So GCC is right.

<sup>(as a rule of thumb, trust the warnings given by the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler which is extremely tested and peer-reviewed, so **trust the compiler** more than your own code)</sup>

You should assign `snr_db = 20.0;` *before* the `for` loop, in your case it is the only sane thing to do.

You could use the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), but that would make your code unreadable:

```
for (int interval = (snr_db = 20.0), 1;  ///unreadable so confusing
```

so I don't recommend doing that.

Comment: I trusted the compiler and I'm assigning it before the for loop. Thank you for clarifying things.

Answer (score 0):

Cause the snr_db in for loop is a temporary variable, not the outer scope variable.

Comment: This just restates the core of an existing answer without explaining anything. Even worse, there's no concept of "temporary variables" in C, you just invented that. Don't write "answers" like this.

Comment: @FelixPalmen and actually there is a concept "temporary variable" in programming language.

Comment: That's an informal term for the usage of the variable and has nothing to do with C. This is in its current form a bad answer.

Comment: Funny, I don't restate what other answers say. I just make the point more clear,  you can vote down, but actually it's not `BAD`.

Comment: I don't know how to put it otherwise ... it **is** bad. It's not *wrong*, but it fails to explain anything (while there was already an exhaustive and good answer!) and needlessly introduces an unrelated term. Questions and answers here should be helpful for future readers and this one probably isn't. Please take the time and learn [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).